# creating a binary matrix using list values

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I am new to python and stack overflow.
I need to create a binary matrix that the value takes 1 if the customers exist in a given list.
For example:
assume a list as [4,5,8].
i need a 10x10 matrix with all zero excepts matrix[4,5],matrix[5,4], matrix[5,8],matrix[8,5] and matrix[4,8], matrix[8,4] are 1.
Is there an easy way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```py
data = [4, 5, 8]
```

You calculate:

```py
matrix = [[int(c in data and r in data and c != r) for c in range(10)] for r in range(10)]
```

You get:

```py
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The solution shown above uses zero-based indexing.